# How to detect scroll position of page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am having trouble with jQuery functionality on my website. What it does, is that it uses the `window.scroll()`  function to recognize when the windows changes its scroll position and at the change calls a few functions to load data from the server.

The problem is the `.scroll()` function is called as soon as there is even a little change in the scroll position and loads data at the bottom; however, what I wish to achieve is to load new data when the scroll/page position reaches at the bottom, like it happens for Facebook feed.

But I am not sure how to detect scroll position using jQuery?

```
function getData() {
  $.getJSON('Get/GetData?no=1', function (responseText) {
    //Load some data from the server
  })
};

$(window).scroll(function () {
    getData();
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect scroll direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154967/how-to-detect-scroll-direction)

Answer (score 376, accepted):

You can extract the scroll position using jQuery's [`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) method

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    // Do something
});
```

Comment: Attaching events to window scroll is a bad idea : see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036850/how-to-detect-page-scroll-to-a-certain-point-in-jquery

Comment: Listening to window scroll isn't bad in and of itself. It's when people try to _do_ things on each firing of that event that trouble occurs.

If you only do something like set a variable's value to the current scroll position, or to true/false, and then make use of _those_ outside the event, you should generally be golden.

Comment: You should consider debouncing when working with this kind of events. See https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: As you already have `event` in function as argument you can get the same data from `event.originalEvent.pageY;`

Comment: I was came here few times. Because I forgot to add jQuery before declare my javascript file. If this not work for you, please check you declare it first.

Answer (score 124):

You are looking for the `window.scrollTop()` function.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(height  > some_number) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 36):

Check here DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/Uhm2J/

```
function getData() {
    $.getJSON('Get/GetData?no=1', function (responseText) {
        //Load some data from the server
    })
};

$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       alert("bottom!");
       // getData();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$(window).scroll( function() { 
 var scrolled_val = $(document).scrollTop().valueOf();
 alert(scrolled_val+ ' = scroll value');
});
```

This is another way of getting the value of scroll.

Answer (score 4):

Now that works for me...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).resize(function(e){
        console.log(e);                   
    });

    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        var sc = $(window).scrollTop();
        console.log(sc);
    });

})
```

it works well... and then you can use JQuery/TweenMax to track elements and control them.

Comment: Please absolutely avoid slurs and bad words. Read the [help].

Answer (score 2):

Store the value of the scroll as changes in HiddenField when around the PostBack retrieves the value and adds the scroll.

```
//jQuery

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    $(window).scrollTop($("#<%=hidScroll.ClientID %>").val());

    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        $("#<%=hidScroll.ClientID %>").val($(window).scrollTop());
    });
});

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prm.add_endRequest(function () {

    $(window).scrollTop($("#<%=hidScroll.ClientID %>").val());

    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        $("#<%=hidScroll.ClientID %>").val($(window).scrollTop());
    });
});

//Page Asp.Net
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidScroll" runat="server" Value="0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add all pages with this code:

JS code:

```
 /* Top btn */
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop()) {
            $('#toTop').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('#toTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });
    var top_btn_html="<topbtn id='toTop' onclick='gotoTop()'>&#8593;</topbtn>";
    $('document').ready(function(){
        $("body").append(top_btn_html);
    });
    function gotoTop(){
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 500);    
    }
    /* Top btn */
```

CSS CODE

```
/*Scrool top btn*/
#toTop{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.div').scroll(function (event) {
 event.preventDefault()
 var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
 if(scroll == 0){
   alert(123)
 }
});
```

This code for chat_boxes for loading previous messages

Answer (score 0):

**GET Scroll Position:**

> var scrolled_val = window.scrollY;

**DETECT Scroll Position:**

```
$(window).scroll
(
     function (event) 
     {
          var scrolled_val = window.scrollY;
          alert(scrolled_val);
     }
 );
```