# get attribute value depending on position from top

Tags: jquery

Got this list of images. I would like to display the value of data-id of the figure which is closest to the 200px from the top of the browser. See when I scroll down i see the values 740 then 756 then 788 etc.

```
  <div id="counter" style="position:fixed;top:10px;left:10px;height:200px;width:200px;"></div>


 <figure style="height:200px;" data-id="740"></figure>
    <figure style="height:200px;" data-id="756"></figure>
    <figure style="height:200px;" data-id="788"></figure>
    <figure style="height:200px;" data-id="920"></figure>
```

Comment: Where is your Code ? JSfiddle huh ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/skiweather/2uwpq1w0/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **.first()** or **:first** to select the first element from a given selector on the page.

e.g.

`$("figure").first()`

`$("figure:first")`

Then to get the **data-id** attribute you can add:

`$("figure:first").data("id")`

Comment: yes, but based on the scroll position on the page. This is not the solution

Comment: I see, this might help you then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441065/how-to-detect-scroll-position-of-page-using-jquery