# div top position relevant to window

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, javascript

I need to get div top position relevant to window.

I used jquery functions such as:

```
scrollTop()
offset()
position()
offset().top
```

**My Problem**
when I open the page on widescreen resolution such as 1360x768 values are differ from normal aspect ratio such as 1024x768

**I want to trigger what ever event when scrolling to certain position... how can I do this without confusion between wide screen/normal screen aspect ratios
because when I used mentioned functions... returned values were differ**

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "div top position"? Do you mean top most DOM element relative to the window? The question you stated is not clear.

Comment: Yes, you can use position function and then get top value of div "position.top".

Comment: `$('div').offset().top` would give you the offset top position relative to the parent body.

Comment: Thanx all I edited my question with more details

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441065/how-to-detect-scroll-position-of-page-using-jquery

Comment: Not a duplicate,,, I asking about specific situation, getting different scroll position values when we open page in widescreen vs normal aspect ratios

Comment: How is there a difference between widescreen versus narrow screen? Either a) you depend on a fixed position relative to the top of the window or b) you look for the current height of some DOM element. I don't see how the window size/aspect ratio affects the method of triggering an event based on the scroll location.

Comment: I don't want to use fixed tags positions, returned values are differ between wire/narrow screens

Answer (score 0):

I thins you should use

```
position: fixed;
```

css style. 
Because fixed can make the element relative to window. That really means a window, not document.

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to use fixed position. is there any other way