# jQuery increase and decrease value on scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want the value to increase when scrolling down and decrease when scrolling up.

This is the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="9.js"></script>
<style>
#addit
{
position:fixed;
top:0px;
left:0px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="addit">
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var x=1;
    x=x+1;
    $("#addit").html(x);
});
```

As I am new to jQuery, I can't find a way for it! 
Can anyone help?

Comment: its already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441065/how-to-detect-scroll-position-of-page-using-jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a variable, just:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $("#addit").html($(window).scrollTop());
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/frmdp7as/)

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $("#addit").html($(window).scrollTop());
});
```