# Scroll top - chrome vs IE

Tags: jquery

I'm having an issue getting some simple code working for both Chrome and IE11 working properly.

Simply:

This works in IEii but not chrome:

```
var s = $('html, body').scrollTop();
    alert (s);
```

And this works in chrome but not IE:

```
var s = $('body').scrollTop();
alert (s);
```

Any help to get it working properly for both browsers?

Thanks,

Comment: scrollTop() getter returns only first matched element in set top value and chrome scrollingElement is the body, not html. That's why `$('html, body').scrollTop()` doesn't work on chrome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect scroll position of page using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441065/how-to-detect-scroll-position-of-page-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about you use window instead of body

```
$(window).scrollTop();
```

Answer (score -3):

Please try below code..

#### var get_scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

#### console.log(get_scroll);

Comment: And where is the OP animating the page?