# Using Jquery to find HTML element / content which occupies pixel position on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to find the HTML element or content which occupies the pixel position on a page. I am using currently using jQuery to find the `scrollTop()` position:

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(scroll);
    // Do something 
});
```

to understand the `$(window).scrollTop()` position, but I'd like to know what occupies the space. E.g., if a user scrolls to '300', what HTML element or content is there?

*Scrolltop code from [How to detect scroll position of page using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441065/how-to-detect-scroll-position-of-page-using-jquery)*

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkElement(el){
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    var elementPosition = el.height() + el.position().top;
    if (elementPosition > scroll &&  elementPosition < windowHeight + scroll){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```