# How to show and hide an element when scrolling the window using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show a border effect when I'll scroll down and reach on the desired section.And it'll be hide when I'll leave that section. Is this possible using jquery?

Comment: Yes it's possible. You'll just need to write the code to do it. http://api.jquery.com

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441065/how-to-detect-scroll-position-of-page-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Using **$(document).on('scroll')**, like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<style>
html,body {
    height:101%;
}

#box-1 {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#333;
}

.border-1 {
    border: 10px solid #696969;
}
</style>
<body>
<h1 id="myTarget">This is the desire section</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor amit. Lorem ipsum dolor amit. Lorem ipsum dolor amit. </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor amit. Lorem ipsum dolor amit. Lorem ipsum dolor amit. </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor amit. Lorem ipsum dolor amit. Lorem ipsum dolor amit. </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor amit. Lorem ipsum dolor amit. Lorem ipsum dolor amit. </p>
<div id="box-1"></div>

<script>
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    var pos = $(this).scrollTop();
    if( pos >= $('#myTarget').offset().top){
        $("#box-1").addClass("border-1").show();
    } else {
        $("#box-1").removeClass("border-1").hide();
    }
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```