# How can i trigger a css class when a reach to a specific div with scroll

Tags: javascript

i am new to Javascript and i would like your help.
I have a code and when you scroll from the top of a page changes css of a class and zooms the images.

What i would like to do is, to put a class in a div ( lets say .start) and  when i reach to that class then to start zoom the image.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    $(".zoom").css({

        backgroundSize: (100 + scroll / 20) + "%"

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this: [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

```
HTML
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">A</div>
  <div class="content">B</div>
  <div id="start" class="content">C</div>
  <div class="zoom"><!-- Image --></div>
</div>


JS
$(window).scroll(function () {
var target = $('#start')[0].getBoundingClientRect(); // id="start" Element

  // Start zoom at #start element's position
  if (target.top - target.height <= 0) {
    $(".zoom").css({
      backgroundSize: (100 + (target.height - target.top) / 20) + "%"
    });
  }
});
```

`getBoundingClientRect()` is returns the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport.

You can check the target Element's position and trigger it.

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/ghlee/uecb26ft

Comment: That worked for a certain div with id="start".
I tried to change $('#start') with $('.start') so i can trigger every div with the class start, but it did not worked.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/oyk2g0  when you see the first start then the background size changes ( works fine ) but because there is a start class in the next div the background size keeps increasing also in the second class zoom. I want EVERYTIME when you see start class to start changing background-size and when you leave and again see another start class then to start increase again the background-size.

Comment: You can check each elements position and implement like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ghlee/vtx4db9e).

Can stop zoom when top position is `< 0` (Over the top, not visible)

Answer (score 0):

I guess [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144113/javascript-jquery-add-class-when-element-comes-into-viewport) is similar to your problem?

You will need to add your zoom class to the element via `.addClass("zoom");` when it is in the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Well not that exactly.

i have this

```
   $(window).scroll(function () {
    $('#currentContent').bind('inview', monitor);
        function monitor(event, visible)
        {
            if(visible)
            {
                 $(window).scroll(function () {
                    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

                    $(".zoom").css({

                        backgroundSize: (100 + scroll / 20) + "%"

                    });
                });

            }
            else
            {
            // element has gone out of the viewport
            }
        }

    });
```

The "problem" is  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
I want the scroll variable to start not from TOP but from the div where i have add a class.
I have tried this  var scroll = $('.currentContent').offset().top;
But nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

This is what [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) was made to do. With this you can watch elements and react when they come into view or intersect with each other.

First you set the options for the IO:

```
let options = {
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 1.0
}

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
```

If you leave out the `root` option it wall default to your browser window, so once an element that you watch comes into viewport, the callback function gets triggered.

Then you specify which elements you want to observe:

let target = document.querySelector('.zoom');
observer.observe(target);

Here we now watch every element with the class zoom.

Last step is to define the callback function:

```
let callback = (entries, observer) => { 
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    // Each entry describes an intersection change for one observed
    // target element:
    // like: $(element).addClass('zoom');
  });
};
```

You can [unobserve an element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/unobserve) if you don't need it anymore, for example if you only want to play the zoom animation only once when it comes into view.

Also check out this example on [how to change bg-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#Result) depending on how much of an element is visible on screen.
Edit: Maybe [this example is more fitting](https://alligator.io/js/intersection-observer/) (see comments) because it actually adds a class when user scrolls to the element.

Last point, you can use [this polyfill from w3c](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver) to support older browsers.

Comment: did you get any errors? what exactly didn't work? Also try to copy the linked example for changing bg-color but instead of bg-color you just add your class.

Comment: The code is too complicated i think. The code that worked is from @ghlee
  
$(window).scroll(function () {
        var target = $('.start')[0].getBoundingClientRect(); // id="start" Element
        if (target.top - target.height <= 0) {
            $(".zoom").css({
                backgroundSize: (100 + (target.height - target.top) / 30) + "%"
            });
        }
       
    });

Comment: But, prntscr.com/oyk2g0 when you see the first start then the background size changes ( works fine ) but because there is a start class in the next div the background size keeps increasing also in the second class zoom. I want EVERYTIME when you see start class to start changing background-size and when you leave and again see another start class then to start increase again the background-size

Comment: i think you are replying to the wrong comment because your code has nothing to do with what I wrote. Delete everything and start from scratch you don't need $(window).scroll(...) anywhere for your problem. You can do it with .scroll() but then you can expect performance issues if you have too many elements.

Comment: Maybe also [check this example](https://alligator.io/js/intersection-observer/), here a class is added (and removed) if an element is in the viewport. You only want to copy the part for adding the class obviously :)

Comment: thank you, but i do not want to add or remove a class. If i add a class the zoom effect will be instant to some point. I want to zoom in as long as you scroll inside a div . When scroll up zoom out and when scroll down zoom in.

Comment: my bad, then check the first example. i thought you want to add a class which will then trigger the zoom effect. Then the example with changing bg-color is what you need, just instead of changing the bg-color you increase (or decrease) the size

Answer (score 0):

To determine if an element with the desired class is in the viewport (i.e., been scrolled to), you could calculate the offset of the `.start` element and compare it with the current scroll value on scroll.

If the element is in the viewport, you could then zoom the image. The below snippet will increase the image size when you reach it. Just zoom past the height of the red area. If you scroll back up, it should get smaller. You may want a different effect, but the same idea applies.

Also, see my comments in the `inViewport` function.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (inViewport($(".start"))) {
    $(".start").css("height", "200px").css("width", "200px");
  } else {
    $(".start").css("height", "50px").css("width", "50px");
  }
});

function inViewport(element) {
  // added extra height so you can see the element change back to smaller size
  // you could remove this value if you just want the element to change size when out of the viewport
  const extra = 50;
  var elementTop = element.offset().top + extra;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + element.outerHeight();
  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};
```

```css
#placeholder {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

.start {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
<img class="start" src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" />
```

Comment: prntscr.com/oyk2g0 when you see the first start then the background size changes ( works fine ) but because there is a start class in the next div the background size keeps increasing also in the second class zoom. I want EVERYTIME when you see start class to start changing background-size and when you leave and again see another start class then to start increase again the background-size.

Comment: what should i put to X if i want to change background size in scroll. 

http://prntscr.com/oyl1sf

Answer (score 0):

Well, you seem to be on the right path. You probably in addition need to pay attention to the `background-size` property. Instead of the JavaScript strongly named `backgroundSize` for the css `background-size` property, accessed through the `style` object of an element like this; `currentElement.style.backgroundSize`, you might want to do this; `"background-size": (100 + scroll / 20) + "%`. Here's a working example that builds upon your existing code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="start">My Zoom Heading</h1>
  <p class="zoom">My zoom area</p>

  <script>
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      var zoomStart = $("#start").offset().top;

      if (scroll >= zoomStart) {
        $(".zoom").css({
          "background-size": (100 + scroll / 10) + "%"
        });
      }
    });
  </script>

  <style>
    #start {
      margin-top: 60px;
    }
    
    .zoom {
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 300px;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      background: url('{some-image-url-here}') no-repeat;
    }
  </style>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well please check the URL.
I would like when i enter the Div with the class start to start the image zooming.
Also there is a second div sith the class start. When you enter AGAIN the next div i would like to start zooming the image but not keep zoom as it does right now.

http://projects.blindhost.gr/test/designer.html