# Change CSS with jQuery if not at the top of the page

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using jQuery to change the CSS elements of the Bootstrap navbar after scrolling. The issue I have is that if you load the page anywhere after the top of the page, the menu won't get smaller until you scroll down - with the below code:

```
var a = $(".nav").offset().top;

$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > a)
    {   
       $('.navbar-fixed-top').css({"background":"#fff"});
       $('.navbar-fixed-top').css({"transition":"0.5s"});
       $('.navbar-fixed-top li a').css({"padding-top":"20px"});
       $('.navbar-fixed-top li a').css({"padding-bottom":"20px"});
    } else {
       $('.navbar-fixed-top').css({"background":"transparent"});
       $('.navbar-fixed-top').css({"transition":"0.5s"});
       $('.navbar-fixed-top li a').css({"padding-top":"40px"});
       $('.navbar-fixed-top li a').css({"padding-bottom":"40px"});
    }
});
```

I've been trying to change it so that if it's not at the top of the page, it'll execute the scrollTop code, but with no luck.

Comment: It sounds like you may be looking for [a way to check the position on the page in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17441121/2341603).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is run only as event listener, so you have to run it manually first. Try this code:

```
var a = $(".nav").offset().top;

function scrollListener(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() > a)
    {   
       $('.navbar-fixed-top').css({"background":"#fff"});
       $('.navbar-fixed-top').css({"transition":"0.5s"});
       $('.navbar-fixed-top li a').css({"padding-top":"20px"});
       $('.navbar-fixed-top li a').css({"padding-bottom":"20px"});
    } else {
       $('.navbar-fixed-top').css({"background":"transparent"});
       $('.navbar-fixed-top').css({"transition":"0.5s"});
       $('.navbar-fixed-top li a').css({"padding-top":"40px"});
       $('.navbar-fixed-top li a').css({"padding-bottom":"40px"});
    }
};

$(document).scroll(scrollListener);

scrollListener();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. It loads as what it should only be right at the top. Only changes when you scroll down - but when you go up, past the point where you loaded it returns to the previous menu.

Comment: Perhaps, would it be better for the menu to always be smaller, and only get bigger if it's touching the top?

Comment: Could you provide online demo?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to run the adjust function on both `scroll` and `load` events. 
Here's an example:

```
(function($) {
    var a = $(".nav").offset().top;

    var adjust = function () {
        if($(document).scrollTop() > a) {   
           $('.navbar-fixed-top').css({"background":"#fff"});
           $('.navbar-fixed-top').css({"transition":"0.5s"});
           $('.navbar-fixed-top li a').css({"padding-top":"20px"});
           $('.navbar-fixed-top li a').css({"padding-bottom":"20px"});
        } else {
           $('.navbar-fixed-top').css({"background":"transparent"});
           $('.navbar-fixed-top').css({"transition":"0.5s"});
           $('.navbar-fixed-top li a').css({"padding-top":"40px"});
           $('.navbar-fixed-top li a').css({"padding-bottom":"40px"});
        }
    }

    $(document).scroll(adjust);
    $(function() { adjust; })
})(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: Look at my solution, your version doesn't deal with `$(this).scrollTop()`

Comment: It's the exact same solution, mine just waits for the `window.load` event to fire and does not pollute the global namespace...

Comment: Try to run your code. Events subscribers have `this` pointer to listened element (in this case it was `document`).
As I can see, you call adjust without any pointer to `document`, so `this` inside is pointed to instance of `adjust` function.

You should suggest `$(function() { adjust.call(document); })` instead.

Comment: @michail_w Unfortunately, this didn't work. It loads as what it should only be right at the top. Only changes when you scroll down - but when you go up, past the point where you loaded it returns to the previous menu