# How to detect if user scroll a certain distance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to detect if a user rolled the bar a certain distance?

I want to trigger an event when user lower the bar in 1000px.
thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect page scroll to a certain point in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036850/how-to-detect-page-scroll-to-a-certain-point-in-jquery)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the [`scroll`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event combined with [`scrollTop`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) function:

```
//when scrolling...
$(window).scroll(function() {

    //if I scroll more than 1000px...
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 1000){
         //do whatever
    }
});
```

Living demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NvfBc/