# controlling audio programmatically on a web page

Tags: html, audio

I know that HTML5 allows audio embedding and control like so:

```html
<audio controls
  src="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.mp3">
Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Audio element.
</audio>
```

but how can i set the volume initially?
And for extra credit-how can i change the tune as the user scrolls past a certain  or ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do easly with the properties via css or with javascript.

Assign at you `<audio>` and id and the set the porperties in proper css
eg:

```
<audio controls  id="my_audio" volume="0.8" 
   src="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.mp3">
  Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Audio element.
</audio>
```

css

```
#my_audio{
   volume: 0.9;     
   height: 10 px;   
   width: 50px;
  }
```

or javascript

```
<script>

    var theAudio = document.getElementById('my_audio');
    theAudio.style.volume = 0.8;

</script>
```

see MDN [ref1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement)  and [ref2](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) for more

Comment: thank you. I guess a way to answer my second question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036850/how-to-detect-page-scroll-to-a-certain-point-in-jquery but that example just fires an alert. An it seems to have a bug, firing the alert multiple times.

Comment: I tried to follow Reigel's recommendation but it didn't work. Here's my example http://jsfiddle.net/okstef/r0nq40ek/

Comment: Please explain better. You need to know how manage an'audio element event?